# Doubt related to Baire Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

We know by BCT that in a complete metric space the countable intersection of open dense sets is dense. 
Will it also be open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Take the irrational numbers $\Bbb{I}$ on the real line.

We have that $\Bbb{I}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}O_n$ where $O_n$ are dense open sets.

But $\Bbb{I}$ is not open.

Comment: Don't you mean intersection?

Comment: To make things explicit, we can take $O_n=\Bbb R\setminus\frac1n\Bbb Z$

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person yes it was a typo...thank you.

Comment: Ok just wondering is it possible the intersection is countable dense?

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person what do you mean countable dense..?

Comment: I mean in your case the counterexample is an uncountable set right? namely the irrationals.  Can it happen that the intersection is a countable set?

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person No, not unless there are isolated points in the whole space. If $X$ has no isolated points and is complete metric, then the intersection will be uncountable.